# Letter 'j' bugged with imagettftext function

Tags: php, png, gd, truetype, imagettftext

I've created a script to generate an avatar by using PHP and all work fine but when there is the letter **j** in `$data1['username']`, the letter erase a part of the previous letter. NOTE : I use calibri bold italic ([Downloaded here](http://www.fontpalace.com/font-download/Calibri+Bold+Italic/))
This is my code :

```
$image = imagecreatefrompng("avatar.png");
    $couleur = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
    $largeur_source = imagesx($image); 
    $fontfile = 'calibri.ttf';
    $angle = 0;
    $police = 18;
    $text_size = imagettfbbox($police, $angle, $fontfile, 'Hub de '.$data2['nom']); 
    $text_size2 = imagettfbbox($police, $angle, $fontfile, $data1['username']); 
    $text_width = (($text_size[2] + $text_size[4]) / 2) - (($text_size[0] + $text_size[6]) / 2);
    $text_width2 = (($text_size2[2] + $text_size2[4]) / 2) - (($text_size2[0] + $text_size2[6]) / 2);
    $x = ($largeur_source - $text_width)/2;
    $x2 = (176 - $text_width2)/2 + 74;
    //imagestring($image, $police, $x, $y, $texte_a_ecrire, $couleur);
    imagettftext($image, $police, $angle, $x2, 175, $couleur, $fontfile, $data1['username']);
    imagettftext($image, $police, $angle, $x, 35, $couleur, $fontfile, 'Hub de '.$data2['nom']);
    imagepng($image);
```

When `$data1['username'] = 'Paj46` the string looks like :
[image: Script's return]

Comment: it's better to calc the width letter by letter. Part of `P` is also cut.

Comment: @moskito-x I'm sorry but I don't really understand what you mean. Can you give me an example ? thx

Comment: Why is the font in the image slanted, even though you use regular Calibri and an angle of 0?

Comment: also this is useless assume $text_size2[2] => 198 // lower right X coordinate
    $text_size2[4] => 198 // upper right X coordinate. You are adding the same value and then diff 2 . means you got 198 again. `($text_size2[2] + $text_size2[4]) /2`

Comment: use `$x2 = ceil((176 - $text_size2[2]) / 2);` if not enough then increment `176`

Comment: @Jongware It's the Calibri Bold Italic font but the angle is 0.

Comment: But the font *name* is for the regular font! Anyway, it seems to indicate `imagettftext` cannot work with pixels extending beyound the bounding box. Either it does not draw them, or it does but they get overdrawn with the next character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your font has no kerning pairs table

look here for [Kerning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning#Digital_typography)

- you have to calculate on integers dont use `x/2` direct `round up` .. `ceil()`
- if you have the width of image in `$largeur_source` use it !
- use `result[2]` or `result[4]` from `imagettfbbox()` to calculate. (values are the same)

---

```
<?php
    $image = imagecreatefrompng("avatar.png");
    $couleur = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);
    $largeur_source = imagesx($image); 
    $fontfile = '59250___.TTF';
    $angle = 0;
    $police = 24;
    $text_size = imagettfbbox($police, $angle, $fontfile, 'Hub de' ); 
    $text_size2 = imagettfbbox($police, $angle, $fontfile, 'username'); 
    $x  = ceil(($largeur_source - $text_size[2])  / 2);
    $x2 = ceil(($largeur_source - $text_size2[2]) / 2);
    imagettftext($image, $police, $angle, $x2, 80, $couleur, $fontfile, 'username');
    imagettftext($image, $police, $angle, $x, 35, $couleur, $fontfile, 'Hub de ');
    imagepng($image);
```

[image]

Comment: I've applicated your suggestions, thx. To do more easly, I've changed the font for Calibri Bold and it's work.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't accept the answer because despite the fact that this helped me, my problem is not really solved because I've changed the font.

Comment: @louis67 : In the first sentence, I pointed out . Something is wrong with the font !!!. **Looks like your font has no kerning pairs table** . Most functions do not work on not valid resources.